# Programmatically Click PrimaryButton of ContentDialog

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, How can you Programmatically click the PrimaryButton of ContentDialog when KeyDown event of a textbox detects that the  Enter has been pressed?  Just trying to add a keyboard short cut to accept the answer In textbox and close the dialogbox all from the keyboard without needing to move the mouse and click ok.

```
private void A1TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        // Programmatically Click PrimaryButton Here        
    }
}

<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App1.ContentDialog1"
    Title="DialogBox"
    Loaded="ContentDialog_Loaded"
    PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

<Grid Name="A1Grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Name="A1TextBox" Grid.Row="0" 
        PlaceholderText="Search String" 
        TextChanged="A1TextBox_TextChanged" 
        KeyDown="A1TextBox_KeyDown"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox Name="A1ListBox" MinHeight="200"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making the button you want to click the "AcceptButton"?

```
//This goes in the form loading method
this.AcceptButton = PrimaryButton;
```

This should turn the button blue, and when pressing enter on the form will result in the click function being called.project

Edit: Just noticed this isn't for winforms.

```
this.DefaultButton = PrimaryButton;
```

Thanks Bill!

Comment: This question is for UWP not WinForms.  UWP doesn't have an AcceptButton property for ContentDialog.

Comment: They renamed WinForm AcceptButton to DefaultButton in UWP.

Comment: ah, sorry, missed that. Still getting used to filters.

Answer (score 2):

Use following Code:

```
RoutedEventArgs f;

private void A1TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick (Sender, f);       
    }
}
```

than he will fire the PrimaryButtonClick Event.

Answer (score 1):

The UWP ContentDialog documentation states:

"You may optionally choose to differentiate one of the three buttons as the dialog's default button. Use the **DefaultButton** property to differentiate one of the buttons. **This button will** receive the Accent Button visual treatment, **respond to the ENTER key automatically, and receive focus when the Dialog is opened unless the dialog's content contains focusable elements.**"

Change ContentDialog as follows:

```
<ContentDialog … DefaultButton="Primary">
```